# @media rule in <style> tag in .cshtml file throws error

Tags: css, razor

Why putting below line

```
<style type="text/css">
    .on-the-fly-behavior {
    background-image: url('particular_ad.png'); 
}
@media (max-width: 300px) {
    .on-the-fly-behavior {
        background-image: url('particular_ad_small.png');
    }
}
</style>
```

in "style" tag in .cshtml file throws error when displaying in the browser:

```
CS0103: The name 'media' does not exist in the current context
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In .cshtml you can not use it as it is because it will be treated as a class or object. you need to put an extra `@` whenever you need to add anything that starts with `@` in an html file. Try using this

```
<style type="text/css">
    .on-the-fly-behavior {
        background-image: url('particular_ad.png'); 
    }
    @@media (max-width: 300px) {
        .on-the-fly-behavior {
            background-image: url('particular_ad_small.png');
        }
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

TRY :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .on-the-fly-behavior {
    background-image: url('particular_ad.png'); 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) { /* add screen and */
    .on-the-fly-behavior {
        background-image: url('particular_ad_small.png');
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?